# Blender texture looks more white

Tags: texturing, uv

I downloaded this model from the site Sketchfab, this is how the model supposed to look like:

[image: reference look]

And here's how it looks like on my side:

[image: on my side]

The shader nodes:

[image: shader nodes]

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you show us that material in the shader editor? Maybe there is just something wrong with your material, it pretty much looks like if emission was enabled slightly or there is something else that bleaches it

Comment: sure but how i can send pics on comments

Comment: https://imgur.com/DsiPMUn

Comment: instead of sending pics in comments it's better to [edit] the question to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image you sent again the issue should be here:

[image]

This second image texture should act as the indicator to which part should be light up by emission and which shouldn't... in that manner, you have to input that image texture with the name **Color**somethingEmission into Emission Value of your principled BSDF, not into Emission Strenght,... in emission strength try some value like 5 and tell me if it works now

The way you set it up is that you are giving your whole object white emission with some slight low value of strenght

Comment: thx for the advite but nope that didn't  help it 
it actually was on sRGB but someone said put it on linear 
by the way the first time i got this model .. the texutres was all black i looked on yt and some guy said change the " Alpha "  to 1.0 i did that and the black texture fixed but the textures became whiters

Comment: wait wait, i got it... i didnt notice it because I saw linear at the top first... your problem is that you have enabled emission for the whole object and not for only parts that are supposed to emit light... I will edit my answer but I thing that you have to put that second texture from emission strength to emission... please post that texture into your question so I can see if I am right

Comment: answer is edited, try second solution

Comment: oh thank u so much that worked

Comment: so it was as I said, that texture is showing that only eyes and those scars on the body should emit light, other those part have emission color and other parts have black color so that emission strength value will only affect places that should be lit up